# Can I share my files through Amazon Cloud Drive?

Tags: amazon, online-storage

I don't have Amazon Cloud Drive but I think of having one.

My question is if I can share my files on Amazon Cloud Drive with others. Let's say give them a URL or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>No. For that particular feature you might want to consider [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/).

Take a look at this comparison: http://techsplurge.com/3485/dropbox-amazon-cloud-drive-detailed-comparison/</del>

> To share your files:
>
> 1. Go to [Your Cloud Drive](http://www.amazon.com/clouddrive).
> 2. Select up to 25 files and/or folders.
> 3. Click **Share**.
> 4. Either share a link by clicking **Get shareable link**, or share by email.
>
> **Note**: When you share a folder you will share all contents of the folder, including any sub-folders it may contain.

[Source](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201015230).

[image]

Comment: You can, as the above answer suggests. However, the recipient will only be able to download ONE item at a time. There is currently no "Download all" option. You might want to keep that in mind.

Comment: There is no "share" button or link. Maybe there was in the past

Answer (score 2):

The actual "share" button is not easy to spot.

[image]

Drive is not a "consumer-ready" product, so very bare bones, but does the job. Suggest putting the files into a zip.